# error: unknown type name '＃include' ＃include <stdio.h>

Tags: c, macos, terminal

When I am using the terminal on the Mac to compile a .c file, I am getting following errors:

[image]

How can I handle these errors?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  for (int i=1; i<=9; i++)
    {
      for (int j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
          printf ("%d * %d = %2d ", j, i, j*i);
        }
      printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you typed at the terminal to get that result?

Comment: try `-lc` flag and you do not need `-c` flag for simple program.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the errors as text and not as an image.

Comment: Chances are good that you have an additional character before the `#` that you have not reproduced in your question.  Perhaps a Unicode byte-order mark, which might come from editing the code with some text editors, depending on settings.

Comment: please tap the blue words "enter image description here" to see what happened, thanks.

Comment: Is what you show as your code exactly what you have in the `01-for_loop.c` file? The error message seems to indicate that it's not the same. The error shows a space between `#` and `include` (which should still be acceptable) but that makes me suspicious of potential other differences. Please show exactly the code you are compiling.

Comment: The code you actually presented in the question is completely fine.  It compiles for me without warning or error and runs as I would expect it to do.

Comment: @Rico I edited your question to show the image directly, but be aware that providing an external link to show what you entered and what your results were is generally frowned upon here. It makes navigating questions more tedious.

Comment: I don't think it does exactly show a space. It looks to me more as if the `#` is taking up two characters' space, but it's positioned more or less exactly in the middle of that space. What to make of that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thank you very much, it was actually the key points, the `#` was taking up two characters' space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an extra character/byte somewhere in there. Here's the text `# include <stdio.h>` annotated to show which character is at which offset:

```
# include <stdio.h>
^^^^^^^^^^^
12345678901
```

As you can see, `<` should be at offset 11, but the second line of your compiler output says it's at offset 12. That suggests that somewhere between the start of the file and the `<` you've got a stray byte that shouldn't be there.

I suggest deleting the line and manually retyping it. It's possible you just copied and pasted it but accidentally picked up some invalid characters/bytes while doing that.

Comment: Thanks, absolutely right!

Comment: I've tried reproducing the `# include <stdio.h>` , also `#  include <stdio.h>` and  `# include  <stdio.h>`  space-based typos, then build on a mac in llvm4.2 and gcc4.2, but could not reproduce the problem. All compiles well...